# DB design for message template with different type of parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Thanks in advance for any ideas of db design for the following system.

I need to automatically generate some messages based on some message templates and a list of parameters, e.g. Hello {0}, do you have any of the following {1}, {2} in {3}?

{0}, {1}, {2}, {3} are all in different data types, which are in separate tables. {0} could be a name from user table, {1} {2} could be from item table, and {3} from some other table.

I need to store all the message formats and the complete messages with filled parameters, which seems not very easy. I'm thinking about the following tables. Are there any better ideas? Thanks!

```
Message_Format
===================================================================================
msgFormatID   int
bodyFormat    varchar  e.g. "Do you have any of the following, {0}, {1}, {2} in {3}?"


Message_Details
======================
msgFormatID        int  
dataIndex          int
specificTableName  varchar => the table name of specific table corresponds to {0},{1}... e.g. User_Table
specificTypeName   varchar => the column name of specific field, e.g. firstName in User_Table
specificTypeID     int     => the id used to query the table, e.g. userID
```

Comment: Is the fact that the data items are in different, specific tables a given constraint or part of your solution?

Comment: it is a given constraint. The message can contain different information from different tables.

Comment: Then overall this is a good direction. How will you identify the column of the specificTableName that contains the value? How will you select the row from that table for the value you need?

Comment: That's the difficulty I'm facing. Currently it stores the specificTableName and specificTypeID, do a select specificTypeID from specificTableName? That seems wonky though.

Comment: OK, I'll move to an answer for more detail...

Answer (score 0):

Overall it looks like a reasonable design but I think you will also need to identify the column and row from the source data table. Your mapping through Message_Details will need a specificColumnName. Then you can `select specificColumnName from specificTableName` but you still need a way to get select the row that you need, but that probably needs to come from the "environment" at the time you are using the template? In your example, you would use the template to determine that {0} comes from specificColumnName "userName" from specificTableName "users" and know that is specificTypeID 1=string (assuming that's what type is for), but which user?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I modified the original post, do you mean something like that?

Comment: BTW, is it common to store table name and column name in commercial database table? If so, a join has to be done separately using separate sql logic, I guess?

Comment: Yes, I think you are on a good track. This is not a common use of DB with mapped names and such, but I think it will suit your purpose to get started.